# How to open a file from Memory Stream

Tags: c#, file, file-io, memorystream

Is it possible to open a file directly from a `MemoryStream` opposed to writing to disk and doing `Process.Start()` ? Specifically a pdf file? If not, I guess I need to write the `MemoryStream` to disk (which is kind of annoying). Could someone then point me to a resource about how to write a `MemoryStream` to Disk?

Comment: (James - I removed the 4.0 dependency from my answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the client :) if the client will accept input from stdin you could *push* the dta to the client. Another possibility might be to write a named-pipes server or a socket-server - not trivial, but it may work.

However, the simplest option is to just grab a temp file and write to that (and delete afterwards).

```
var file = Path.GetTempFileName();
using(var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(file))
{
    var buffer = memStream.GetBuffer();
    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, (int)memStream.Length);
}
```

Remember to clean up the file when you are done.

Comment: Or use `WriteTo` (for non 4.0)

Comment: @Magnus - I removed that; realised that I can use the back-buffer from MemoryStream

Answer (score 1):

Path.GetTempFileName() returns file name with '.tmp' extension, therefore you cant't use Process.Start() that needs windows file association via extension.

Answer (score 0):

If by opening a file, you mean something like starting Adobe Reader for PDF files, then yes, you have to write it to a file. That is, unless the application provides you with some API do that.

One way to write a stream to file would be:

```
using (var memoryStream = /* create the memory stream */)
using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
{
    memoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
}
```