# Open document with word, without path

Tags: c#, file, memorystream

I'm searching how to open a document with word, without its path.

I get my document like this :

```
byte[] text = item.Doc;
```

The document comes directly from database.

I only found way to open with a path... So with my doc, I must open it, and then run saveAs of word application (choice between pdf, doc etc...).

I can store it in a `MemoryStream`, but, what can I do with it next?

Found this [How to open a file from Memory Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236602/how-to-open-a-file-from-memory-stream), but not helping me.

Comment: Why can't you save the file to disk?

Comment: Save them, open them, create pdf(or another file) with it? Isn't that too much, if I can directly open word with my object, and then create pdf?? If there is a lot of document, that makes a lot of new document.

Comment: It's ok if I delete them after saving the new file. I was hoping there exists a way to do it without saving file but whatever.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
    string fileName = "Test.doc";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true);
    string  strContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Reader.Close();
    Response.Write(strContents);
    Response.End();
```

--SJ

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, this is not about ASP.NET response.